# Using jQuery's .each feature when page is constantly updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I've been trying to get to find a solution for this all day but can't think of a good one that I can get working.

Basically, I made some jQuery/javascript code that runs an each() loop for certain items on a web page. This works well, but the page it runs on updates when you scroll to the bottom, adding more results. At the moment, my script can only go through as many items as there are loaded on the page. I would love for it to be able to go through all of them that are loaded, then scroll to the bottom and go through all the new results and continually repeat this process.

I've tried a lot of different solutions but can't seem to make one that works well.

Any help would definitely be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Edit:

Here are some of the concepts I've tried so far:

1. Place the code in a while loop and add an offset so it skips all of the items its already gone over

   ```
   var a = 0;
   var offset = 0;
   while (a == 0) {
       jQuery('.Grid-cell .js-stream-item .ProfileCard').each(function (i, ele) { 
           if (i >= offset) {
               //Run script
           }
       });
       offset = offset + 18; //18 is how many new items are added each time
       setTimeout(function () {
               jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'fast'); //To scroll to the bottom
       }, 5000); 
   }
   ```
2. Place code in while loop but no offset

(Similar to previous but offset removed since I figured it could just runover the ones already done)

3. This one was a bit more experimental since I was getting desperate after the previous attempts failed. Basically, I added a hidden checkbox, then I put my script and the each loop inside of a function. Then whenever the checkbox was clicked it would run the function which ran my script and once the each loop was complete it would scroll to the bottom of the page and click the checkbox to make the function go again

   ```
   $( ".Footer-copyright" ).append( "<input type='checkbox' class='functionclass' style='display:none' value='no' />" );

   jQuery(".functionclass").on("click", function() {
           myfunction();
   })

   function myfunction() {
           jQuery('.Grid-cell .js-stream-item .ProfileCard').each(function (i, ele) {
                   //Run script
           });
           jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'fast');
           jQuery(".functionclass").click();
   }

   jQuery(".functionclass").click();
   ```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Highly recommend posting some code examples, otherwise people here will generally not help you, or be able to.

Comment: @JacinTattersall I'll add some code examples now, thanks for the tip

Comment: @JacinTattersall Tried my best to add some code samples. I apologise if they're formatted a bit weird, it was a little bit fiddly for me to add them

Comment: Have you considered incorporating a scroll function?

Comment: Call your function whenver scroll event happens it is just a tip

Comment: @iPzard Would this be a function which makes the page scroll or are you saying to call the function whenever the page scrolls?

Comment: @Kannan Thanks for the tip! I'll look into making it run whenever a scroll event happens

Comment: @Hydrone whenever the scroll happens, but if you only want to affect new elements, you should add a class to elements once they've been processed, then in the each function nest the code in something like if(!('.Grid-cell .js-stream-item .ProfileCard').hasClass('newclassname')) { code nested in here instead }. Then it will only run the each function for unprocessed elements.

Comment: @iPzard That is actually a really great idea. My method which I posted as an answer works decently, but I think your solution is better. I'll likely look into implementing that in the future

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe I've found a solution to my issue. It's not exactly the cleanest solution ever, but it seems to get the job done. Basically, I've put the task inside of a setInterval() function and so it will now complete the task every 5 seconds and will scroll to the bottom after 15 tasks. This allows it to get an updated list of all of the elements every time it runs. Here is the code for anyone curious:

```
var i = 0;
task = setInterval(function(){
    var elements = jQuery(".Grid-cell .js-stream-item .ProfileCard"); //Gets all of the elemnts
    var element = jQuery(elements[i]); //Gets the element for the attempt number
    //Completes task
    if (i % 15 === 0){
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'fast'); //Scrolls to bottom when attempt number is divisible by 15
    }
    i++;
}, 5000);
```